# Azure web app (Linux) started throwing font error for apache poi xlsx export

Tags: java-8, fonts, azure-web-app-service, apache-poi, xlsx

I have Java application which uses apache poi to generate xlsx export.
The app is deployed on Azure app service as web app on Linux setup and it was working fine since many months (No Font config was ever installed on Azure web service). but suddenly it started throwing error on worksheet creation method saying Font not found.

below is the stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048900166Z  at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048903666Z  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048907266Z  at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048910866Z  at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.getFont2D(Font.java:497)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048914366Z  at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.canDisplayUpTo(Font.java:2250)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048917866Z  at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.singleFont(TextLayout.java:469)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048924066Z  at java.desktop/java.awt.font.TextLayout.<init>(TextLayout.java:530)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048927967Z  at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(SheetUtil.java:273)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048931467Z  at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.AutoSizeColumnTracker.<init>(AutoSizeColumnTracker.java:117)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048935167Z  at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.<init>(SXSSFSheet.java:82)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048938867Z  at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createAndRegisterSXSSFSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:674)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048942367Z  at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook.createSheet(SXSSFWorkbook.java:695)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.048946167Z  at org.xxx.xxx.utils.EXCELReportExporter.writeHeaderLine(EXCELBenchReportExporter.java:28)
```

and deep down in stacktrace

```
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049101970Z Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049105470Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049109070Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049112670Z  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049116270Z  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049119870Z  at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:84)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049123370Z  ... 156 common frames omitted
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049126870Z Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049130370Z  at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049133970Z  at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049137571Z  at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049141071Z  at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049144671Z  at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:379)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049148171Z  at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049151671Z  at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:324)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049155371Z  at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049158971Z  at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
2022-03-04T11:49:12.049162671Z  ... 161 common frames omitted
```

Apparently there is no change in the application and environment is made.

Same app is tested on Windows & Linux with JDK 8 and 11 and it is still working fine locally.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you figure this out?  I'm running into same issue with jasper reports...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Apache Tomcat 8.5 have a look to the automatic update in the configuration tab on Azure Portal.
In the newest version (> 8.5.66) the Docker image of the service contains also an update of Java (not the version but the "provider" - they switched to OpenJDK) and there are no fonts installed causing the problem.

I fix it rollbacking to the 8.5.66 version

Answer (score 3):

Apologies you're experiencing this issue.

Kindly check if Java version on Web App is set to auto-update.
This may cause the Java minor version to change to the most recent one and may throw exceptions on some API calls.

As outlined in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/configure-language-java?pivots=platform-linux#choosing-a-java-runtime-version)- It is recommend to use a fixed version for production environments and not auto-update.

To update the Java version, please try these steps:

1.Navigate to your WebApp on Azure Portal

2.Select the `Configuration` tab under `Settings` blade, and then `General Settings`.

3.If you have "Java SE (Embedded Web Server) (auto-update)” selected under “Java web server” option, then change the `Java minor version` to  **11.0.11**. Now, check to see if it helps.

[image: Java version select]

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue: [Apache POI FontConfiguration NPE on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71354087/apache-poi-fontconfiguration-npe-on-azure). The only workaround I found for the moment, is to set the minor java version to "11.0.11". I created a GitHub ticket also: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21540. The problem I have is that I didn't find a solution to force the minor version using an "az webapp create" command.

Comment: What I found finally is that it is possible to specify Java minor version on a Yaml Azure Devops deployment pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently having the same issue. A temporary fix I did is to remove all the styling and formatting. I think this is an issue on the azure app service container itself. I've raised this question to the Azure community and will update here once I get an answer.

Another workaround would be to deploy the app in a custom container.

Answer (score 1):

For Apache Tomcat 9 works if you choose tomcat version 9.0.46