# Apache POI FontConfiguration NPE on Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-webapps

I have a Azure Linux Webapp using Apache poi that is raising the following error:

```
java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.desktop/sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)
at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:379)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.desktop/sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:324)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:56)
... 198 common frames omitted
```

I have seen that such error can happen using openjdk, and can be solved doing some conf, but how to solve this on Azure?

Doing some tests, I have found that it is working fine using java 11.0.11 instead of last default one 11.0.12, the thing is that I didn't found any way to force the minor version of java using "az webapp create" command. So I am stuck here...

Comment: I have created a ticket on Github to find an solution from Azure team:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21540

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating webapp using [--runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-create-examples) in azure-cli:

For example:

```
az webapp create -g MyResourceGroup -p MyPlan -n MyUniqueAppName --runtime "java|11|Java SE|11"
```

If that doesn’t work, for a workaround, you can try selecting the required version from configuration blade on portal:
[image]
References: [java 8 - Azure web app (Linux) started throwing font error for apache poi xlsx export - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71351655/azure-web-app-linux-started-throwing-font-error-for-apache-poi-xlsx-export/71435489#71435489) , [Java NPE error and java minor version selection · Issue #21540 · Azure/azure-cli · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21540) and [azure - Problem in Powershell with the --runtime command setting up Jenkins pipeline - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54863650/problem-in-powershell-with-the-runtime-command-setting-up-jenkins-pipeline)

Comment: I have got the following message: "Linux Runtime 'java|11|Java|SE|11' is not supported. Please invoke 'az webapp list-runtimes --linux' to cross check". Your solution is only for Windows Webapp I suppose?

Comment: Yes, as of now it’s only possible for windows web app. For Linux, use the configuration option on Azure Portal to set the patch version.

Comment: What I finally found, is that it is possible to specify java minor version on a Yamel Azure Devops pipeline, doing something like: 

task: AzureWebApp@1
displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
inputs:
azureSubscription: MY_SUBS
appType: webAppLinux
appName: MY_APP_NAME
package: MY_PACKAGE
runtimeStack: 'JAVA|11.0.11'

Answer (score 0):

What I finally found, is that it is possible to specify java minor version on a Yaml Azure Devops pipeline, doing something like:

```
- task: AzureWebApp@1
  displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: MY_SUBS
    appType: webAppLinux
    appName: MY_APP_NAME
    package: MY_PACKAGE
    runtimeStack: 'JAVA|11.0.11'
```

Available minor versions can be found on file: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-ux/blob/dev/server/src/stacks/2020-10-01/stacks/web-app-stacks/JavaContainers.ts